# Yii2 exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, database, yii2, console, config

I have an advanced yii2 template. I'm trying to create a console command.
I've created a controller class  and action incide console/controllers folder:

```
namespace console\controllers;

use yii\console\Controller;

class WorkModelController extends Controller
{
    public function actionValidate(){}
}
```

My action should connect with mysql database, select some data and do something with it. When I running the command: yii work-model/validate I get this error:

> C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost>yii work-model/validate Exception
>   'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'
>
> in
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php:56

My console/config/main.php and main-local.php files contain next db-config:

```
'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
];
```

When I trying connect to the database from another part of app all works fine, but when I trying connect from console I get this error.

Please, help me slove this error.

Comment: Just run `apt-get install php5-mysql` or `apt-get install php7-mysql`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to run `php -me` from the cli and make sure pdo_mysql is there.. 
if not, then u need to enable it from your php.ini config.

Sometime, when u use server stack such as lamp/xampp, u probably missed out from resync your environment path to use the same version of `php.ini` of your server stack. to do this, u may simply check/compare php.ini path from both phpinfo() from the browser and php -i from the cli

Comment: Hi @kidzen I really liked your answer.
I am having a hell with php versions and extensions.
I just modified the path to use the same php v as wampp. when I run php -v it appears that I am running the same version, but its not seen the same extensions. Any idea?

Comment: Ho, thanks I found it, apparently, wampp uses two different php.ini files, one for the server and one for the php script. I made it work, thanks for the tip.